# Listen to events "close enough" to the element

Tags: javascript, css, events

I'm looking for a technique, example or lib for providing a buffer area around an element to pick up click and hover events.

Specifically this is for a thin separator that I want to have a larger click target.

Any thoughts would be great. The only requirement is that it cannot affect the style of the rest of the page or other nearby click regions (lowest priority event handler).

---

***Update This is where I'm at:***

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="box">
      Hi there
      <div class="buffer"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="test">Hi there, I should still be clickable</span>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box > .buffer {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var box = document.querySelector('.box');
box.onclick = function(e) {
  alert('clicked on buffer')
}

var span = document.querySelector('.test');
span.onclick = function(e) {
  alert('clicked on span')
}​
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ScSEe/

Only remaining issue is that the buffer squelches nearby click regions.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use event delegation by putting the click handler on the nearest container that holds all the targeted elements, then test the `event.clientX/Y` and compare it to the boundaries of the targeted elements. If one of the elements is in range of where the click happened, run the code against that element.

Comment: Never heard of that. For a click region, you will need to use an invisible element; and positioning that in a responsive manner is not easy without possibly affecting some styles.

Comment: This seems to be the most reasonable approach (I've been playing with other div-related ideas) My main concern how do you know when it moves to update, and it's not as performant as placing a div down.

Comment: The boundary calculation would need to happen at each each event to be safe.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the padding, then setting the margin by a negative amount increase the hit area?  (eg. `padding: 1em; margin: -1em`).

Comment: This will break existing padding and margin (if there are any)

Comment: Unless borders or backgrounds are involved, it's just a matter of figuring out how much padding to add vs. how much margin to take away.  If the original margin is `1em 0`, then `padding: 1em 0; margin: 0` would put it in the same position.  Want a bigger hit area?  Then `padding: 2em 0; margin: -1em 0`

Comment: But that would affect the flow of the page (unless absolutely positioned or similar)

Answer (score 3):

I found an elegant solution, however it only works with non-`static`-positioned elements:

```
<div id="target" style="position:relative/* for example */; z-index:0;">
    <!-- just place this div into the target element: -->
    <div style="
      z-index:-1; /* placed directly behind parent element */
      position:absolute; /* needed for the below to work */
      top:-10px; left:-10px; bottom:-10px; right:-10px; /* around the parent */
     " />
     …
</div>
```

Clicks in that invisble area will get delegated to the parent element, even when they happened outside it. The positioning code makes the "buffer area" always be a little bigger than the layout parent (closest non-static ancestor with `z-index`), no matter of size or position (also when animated etc).

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ndC8b/2/)

Comment: Awesome. Like my idea except your smartly put it below so that elements on top still get the click events. Very smart!

Comment: Cool, using the separator as a parent might just make it work nicely - going to give this a go now and will update with my findings after. Thanks man.

Comment: So, I can't get events to trigger from the buffer (hover, click) events. Only when you click on the actual element do you get the events that could be applied to the buffer (opposite of the question). Also, it seems that the negative z-index actually events from triggering

Comment: prevents events from triggering*

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for the hint. I've investigated a little and found that the `z-index:-1` actually stacked them behind the `<body>` (document root) instead of the `#parent`, and as the body did overlap *only some* areas of the buffer, it worked depending on where you clicked (Urgh).

Comment: The solution is the give the parent a `z-index` itself, so that it introduces a [new *stacking context*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context). `z-index:-1` makes the buffer now appear between background&borders of the parent and its descendants (instead of behind the background as before). But that doesn't matter us as the buffer is transparent (now with border instead of background for demonstration). Fiddle updated.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for all your help. I'm not sure that you even need the z-index, though. Did you take a look at my example, http://jsfiddle.net/ScSEe/ ? Maybe I'm missing something that the z-index adds though..

Comment: @Matt: Sure, only the buffer makes all element in the `#box` unresponsible, as it catches their clicks - see http://jsfiddle.net/ScSEe/1/. With a z-index, you could click the link. Maybe not required in your particular use case, of course.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting an invisible `div` element at a higher z-index than the rest of the elements to catch these events?

```
<div id="click_region" style="z-index:1000; visibility:hidden;"></div>

$("div#click_region").click(function(){/*do yo thang*/};
```

Comment: How about putting this as a comment?

Comment: ideally it would move as this element moves - it's a separator after all. I could see that getting messy very quickly. Also it would probably affect nearby click regions

Comment: @Matt you could place it relative to the element you speak of and even have its height determined by this other element using Javascript, let me edit quickly...

Answer (score 0):

You could place the element inside a transparent div, and setting some padding as the separator area, then you just attach the click callback to the parent.

Comment: that would likely affect the flow of the rest of the page. I'm trying to avoid placing the target element within another element.

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS ::before and/or ::after pseudo-elements?

Comment: Tried this approach, couldn't figure out a reasonable way of making it work. I couldn't find a way to attach hover/click events to ::before and ::after elements.

Comment: Have you tried ::hover? Also, from what I've read, you'll need to have `content: ''` in them for them to do anything. I'm still trying to figure out how to use pseudo-elements so don't assume it'll work.